# What is wrong, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'tbl_rules_rulID'.?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two related tables, and automatic generated controller with view.
I get this error when i tru to open index, list of all records:

> **Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> **Exception Details:** System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'tbl_rules_rulID'.

Here model tbl_rules

```
public class tbl_rules
    {
     public tbl_rules()
        {
            tbl_users = new HashSet<tbl_users>();
        }

        [Key]
        [DisplayName("ID")]
        public int rulID { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Изберете Овластување")]
        [DisplayName("Овластување")]
        public string Rule_Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<tbl_users> tbl_users { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is model tbl_users:

```
public class tbl_users
{
    [Key]
    [DisplayName("ID")]
    public int uID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Ве молиме внесете име на Агентот")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [DisplayName("Агент")]
    [MaxLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Максимален број на карактери за {0} 20")]
    public string user_ime { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Ве молиме внесете Username")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [DisplayName("Username")]
    public string username { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Ве молиме внесете Password")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [DisplayName("Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Ве молиме внесете телефонски број")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [DisplayName("Телефон")]
    public string tel { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Ве молиме внесете Белешка.")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [DisplayName("Белешка")]
    public string note { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Активен?")]
    public bool active { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Статус")]
    public bool IsOnline { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Овластување")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Изберете Овластување")]
    public int rullID { get; set; }
    private DateTime? modified1;
    public DateTime modified
    {
        get { return modified1 ?? DateTime.Now; }
        set { modified1 = value; }
    }
    public virtual tbl_rules tbl_rules { get; set; }
}
```

Contoller code:

```
  public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.tbl_users.ToList());
        }
```

tbl_rules SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_rules] (
    [rulID]     INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Rule_Name] NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([rulID] ASC)
);
```

tbl_users SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_users] (
    [uID]      INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [user_ime] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [username] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Password] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [tel]      NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [note]     NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [active]   BIT           NOT NULL,
    [rullID]   INT           NOT NULL,
    [modified] DATETIME      DEFAULT (getdate()) NOT NULL,
    [IsOnline] BIT           NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([uID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [UserName] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([username] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [ZaRules] FOREIGN KEY ([rullID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[tbl_rules] ([rulID])
);
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Don't post screenshots of your code. Post the code definitions of your SQL tables. And more importantly: post the full exception message and stack trace!

Comment: Thank you , Updated

Comment: The navigation property in tbl_users does not follow convention, the rule id field is named differently between the tables. You must manually map it or change the database to follow EF convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF can't map correctly relation.
You can rename your FK in user class

```
public int rulID { get; set; }
```

intead of

```
public int rullID { get; set; }
```

Or you can add Annotation:

```
    [ForeignKey("rullID ")]
    public virtual tbl_rules tbl_rules { get; set; }
```

both ways should fix you broblem.

Comment: Thank you, second solution is better for me and it`s work. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing these two should be the same?
from rules:

```
public int rulID { get; set; }
```

from users:

```
public int rullID { get; set; }
```

So indeed, your `rules` table has no column `rullID`, as your error message clearly tells you.

Avoid these kind of hard-to-see typo's by simply calling the column `RuleId`. Saving one character ins't worth the trouble.

Just to make it clear: the error message you show probably comes from code you have not posted. Somewhere you are referring to `tbl_rules_rulID` and that column does indeed not exist. So either fix the reference or create that column.

Comment: In tbl_rules primary key name is rulID,  but in tbl_users column name is rullID, i tthink it is ok, because also FK is created property in database relationship.

Comment: It is not ok if you get errors. Just get things sorted out correctly. It's a good habit and it may help avoid people maintaining your code trying to harm you ;) You error message clearly indicates that somewhere you are referring to rules:rullID, a column that clearly does not exist.